# Installing PEAR on PHP 5?

Tags: php, pear

I want to install PEAR on PHP 5, so I can use Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer.

I don`t know how to install it on my ISP nor my personal MacBook.

Thoughts for both?

Answer (score 3):

The [PEAR Manual](http://pear.php.net/distributions/manual/pear_manual_en.html.gz) has a quite extensive list of [instructions](http://pear.php.net/distributions/manual/pear_manual_en.html.gz#installation.getting) on how to install the PEAR manager on Windows, *NIX and Mac OS X. The manual also has a section on installing [PEAR remotely](http://pear.php.net/distributions/manual/pear_manual_en.html.gz#AEN1993), for example using FTP. Following those instructions, you should be able to install PEAR (nearly) anywhere. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, do this:

```
pear install Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer
```

You can also download the package directly here without using PEAR: http://download.pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.1.tgz. It's pretty easy to use if you have the script located anywhere within your include path.

Comment: But I need Pear installed, correct? I dont see anything that shipped called pear with my MacBook

Comment: Mac OS X ships with PHP and PEAR; you run it from the command line in Terminal.

Comment: ok, I have PEAR going now, thanks 

Where do I put the Spreadsheet_Excel_Write now and test?

Answer (score 2):

For your personal computer, using the "pear" script that ships with most PHP distributions  is a good idea.

For shared hosting, you can

- Track your dependencies manually, and copy all the appropriate files to the server yourself
- With pear installed, do *"pear install -R/my/root_dir -a Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer"*. This will install the package and all dependencies to the specified root directory. Copy this installation to your webhost.

You should also have a look at *"pear help"* and *"pear help install"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install pear to your isp's core. But you can install the individual files from pear's site and upload them to your host:

http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/download